# How to work with http web server via file socket in perl?

Tags: perl

It is possible to work with web server living in file socket with linux commands:

```
# /bin/echo -e "GET /containers/json?all=1 HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock ; echo ''
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 03 Jan 2016 23:31:54 GMT
Content-Length: 2

[]
#
```

How can I do the same thing using Perl modules? I would prefer to do the same thing with [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny), but I can't figure out how to use it with file socket.

For now I'm just using perl `system()` but I want to use HTTP::Tiny to make code simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a way to make *HTTP::Tiny* use UNIX sockets but I did find a way to make LWP work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Protocol::http::SocketUnixAlt;

my $socket = "/var/run/docker.sock";
my $geturi = "/containers/json?all=1"; #GET

LWP::Protocol::implementor( http => 'LWP::Protocol::http::SocketUnixAlt' );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->get("http:/var/run/docker.sock/"."$geturi");
print $res->content;
```

There's also [a couple of docker modules in CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=docker&search_type=modules) if you think that manually doing HTTP requests is too much of a hassle and want another abstraction layer.

Comment: Thank you! Frankly speaking I don't like LWP (I think it is too complex), and HTTP::Tiny has a great advantage that it is shipped with perl. My task is too simple to use some huge module (Net::Docker needs AnyEvent, Moo). My task is to write an analog to `docker ps -a` that fits on my screen — https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/a24424d6d5717fcd7139

Comment: @bessarabov yea, LWP has a huge overhead. But well, unless someone builds a huge system of "implementors" like LWP did and PRs it into HTTP::Tiny, doing HTTP over UNIX sockets may remain impossible to do in HTTP::Tiny.

Comment: also, since HTTP::Tiny uses IO::Socket::IP maybe it would be simpler to make it use IO::Socket::UNIX (still, the ::TIny repo seems very inactive, since August.)

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP::Tiny::UNIX](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny::UNIX) will do what you want.  From the docs:

> This is a subclass of HTTP::Tiny to connect to HTTP server over Unix socket.

I'm using Starman to spawn a unix-socket only HTTP daemon which I connect to with an HTTP::Tiny::UNIX client.  Works great.